# Arranging Div's with Headers

Tags: css

I a trying to stack 3 div's side by side. Here's a sample div

```
<!-- This is first div -->
<div id="divone" style="text-align: center;">
<span style="font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Some Message Here</strong></span>
   <div style="text-align: center;">
     <form action="https://www.somesomesomesome.com" method="post">
     </form>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Similarly I need two more divs to be aligned sidebyside with div one -->
```

How can I do it using **inline** CSS? The width of each div can be 200px with no limit on height.

OUTPUT Required

```
--------------------    --------------------       --------------------
DIV ONE                    DIV TWO                      DIV THREE
--------------------     --------------------      --------------------


FORM ELEMENT                FORM ELEMENT                FORM ELEMENT

--------------------     --------------------     --------------------
```

Comment: unfortunately the main css file is not accessible and I have to test this out without the file.

Comment: 1) your example only shows two divs 2) inline css as a habit you should abandon as soon as possible. Even if the main css is not accessable you can either include a second css file or use style tags.

Comment: updated code for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

Just because you can't change the stylesheet, doesn't mean you have to use ugly inline styles.

Add this to your `<head>`:

```
<style>
.three-columns{
  width: 100%; /* or any width you like */
}
.three-columns .column{
  float: left;
  width: 33%; /* or less if you're using margins, padding, borders, etc */
}
</style>
```

Then in the page,

```
<div class="three-columns">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

You can do all your additional css inside a style tag in the head. (Technically, I think you can use it outside the header, but try not to)

Comment: Theoretically, style tags are only allowed in the head. Practically it's also works in the body tag. HTML 5 has a new attribute which makes those style tags in the body valid by applying their according rules only to a subtree of the markup. It looks like `<style scoped>...` but has very poor support atm.

Comment: +1'd. Yeah you can use `<style>` anywhere unfortuneately. I learned the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ul style="list-style: none;"> 
<li>
    <div id="divone" style="">
        <span style="font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Some Message Here</strong></span>
           <div style="text-align: center;">
             <form action="https://www.somesomesomesome.com" method="post">
             </form>
           </div>
    </div>
</li>    
<li>
     <div id="divtwo" style="">
        <span style="font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Some Message Here</strong></span>
           <div style="text-align: center;">
             <form action="https://www.somesomesomesome.com" method="post">
             </form>
           </div>
    </div>
</li>    
<li>
     <div id="divthree" style="t">
        <span style="font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Some Message Here</strong></span>
           <div style="text-align: center;">
             <form action="https://www.somesomesomesome.com" method="post">
             </form>
           </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Demo here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7MZqN/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="divone" style="text-align: center; width:33.33333%; float:left;">
  <span style="font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Some Message Here</strong></span></div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
     <form action="https://www.somesomesomesome.com" method="post">
     </form>
  </div>

 <div id="divtwo" style="text-align: center; width:33.33333%; float:left;">
  <span style="font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Some Message Here</strong></span></div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
     <form action="https://www.somesomesomesome.com" method="post">
     </form>
  </div>

 <div id="divthree" style="text-align: center; width:33.33333%; float:left;">
  <span style="font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Some Message Here</strong></span></div>
  <div style="text-align: center;">
     <form action="https://www.somesomesomesome.com" method="post">
     </form>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div><!-- this is a clearfix div -->
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EnkP5/

UPDATE: i just saw where you wanted the width to be 200px; Change the width from 33.33333% to 200px;

Make sure that the div that all three of these other divs sit in, are more than 600px wide.
​

Comment: Awesome! How can I add a border around the div as well as borders separating each div?

Comment: to the inline styling of each div, you can just add `border: 1px solid black;` ... Im kinda confused to what you mean by a border separating each one? Unless you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EnkP5/1/

Comment: And when adding borders or padding... take in mind that they always extend your div width plus the width size itself... 200px = 200px; 200px + 2px border = 202px

Comment: except when you declare `box-sizing:border-box` (with according vendor prefixes) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set `display: inline-block;` to have the `div`s side-by-side, as follows:

```
<div id="divone" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; width: 200px;">
<span style="font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Some Message Here</strong></span>
   <div style="text-align: center;">
     <form action="https://www.somesomesomesome.com" method="post">
     </form>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="divtwo" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; width: 200px;">
<span style="font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Some Message Here</strong></span>
   <div style="text-align: center;">
     <form action="https://www.somesomesomesome.com" method="post">
     </form>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="divthree" style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; width: 200px;">
<span style="font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Some Message Here</strong></span>
   <div style="text-align: center;">
     <form action="https://www.somesomesomesome.com" method="post">
     </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How you define the width [min-width/width(%)/width(px)/width(em)] is at your discretion..